# dragonframe closes unexpectedly after few seconds

Tags: macos, animation, expected-exception

the software closes after a couple of seconds, after starting it.
can anyone understand the reason?

```
Process: Dragonframe [777]
Path: /Applications/Dragonframe/Dragonframe.app/Contents/MacOS/Dragonframe
Identifier: com.dzed.Dragonframe
Version: 3.6.1 (???)
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process: ??? [1]
Responsible: Dragonframe [777]
User ID: 501
```

https://pastebin.com/gaekAHPY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the issue is that you are using pirated software.

Comment: Could you explain how you can tell please?

Comment: Yes. As the software developer, we recognize that the version in the log file is an old version, and one known to have been hacked by pirates. Any user with a valid license would have upgraded a long time ago. Plus, the software has some self-destruct mechanisms that can detect piracy, and then fail catastrophically.

Comment: thank you so much, now I understood what the problem was